# jupyter notebook does not see the code between blocks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Jupyter Notebook and stumbled upon weird issue recently. After reloading my notebook, as usually I decided to enter the server and start editing my project. But after trying to run an individual block of code, it shows: "'variable' is not defined", regardless of having it in the previous block. Let me show you an example to demonstrate my problem.

[image]

as you can see is shows: 'movies' is not defined, however this variable exists in the upper block of code, same thing with 'dataset'.

What can cause such an issue and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to run the cell where the variable is defined. Not much else to say about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code always runs line by line, even in jupyter notebook. If you look into your own image, then you can see that you need to fix the issue with reading the dataset. It might happen because you haven't initialized the variable dataset and used it directly. In my opinion, it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

***Once someone said*** : "Kernels are responsible for executing code and managing system resources. When a kernel is restarted, it essentially starts fresh, discarding any previous state or memory associated with the previous session. This includes any labels or variables that were defined within that session."

Simply put every time you restart your kernel you have to run every block again as previous variables are lost.